# Why fetch gives response like this?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I got this kind of response from fetch when I inspect it in the console, as shown in the picture. However, when i check from the devtool `Network`, it shows the correct error response. Any idea on how to deal with this?

```
export function loginRequest(data){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let tmp = Object.assign({},data)    
    var request = new Request('https://aaa.com/json', {
      method: 'POST', 
      mode: 'cors', 
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      })
    });
    fetch(request).then((res)=>{          
      alert(JSON.stringify(res))
      dispatch({
        type: types.LOGIN,
        data: res
      })
    }).catch(err =>{

          alert(JSON.stringify(err))
          alert(err.errMsg)
          dispatch({
             type: types.LOGIN,
             data: data
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
    })

  }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Try providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response to JSON to see the response that matches what you see in the network tab.

```
fetch('//offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories')
// First you can deal with the response, checking status code, headers, etc.
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }

    // This is the line you are missing
    return response.json();
})
// Now you will see the proper JSON response that should match
// what you see in the network tab.
.then(function(stories) {
    console.log(stories);
});
```

When using `fetch`, you can see the raw response, which is what your screenshot seems to be, and then you can parse it to JSON to see the body of the response as you are expecting. This allows more fine-tuned control of error handling, responses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) where you don't have to parse your `response` and don't have to manually `reject` if there's `400` errors, it will go to `catch` instead.